# Trying to calculate sum of odd numbers in given range (java) - bug in a code?

Tags: java, sum

I am taking an Udemy course, and I have a problem with a challenge. The author seems to be unwilling to give any advice, so I am asking here.

THe challenge is to create a code using for loop that will calculate sum of odd numbers in any given range (range is defined by 'start' and 'end' parameters). First method (isOdd) checks if the number is odd, the second calculates the sum.

InteliJ gives me now warnings or errors, but when testing, the code is not displaying correct results. I have no idea where the bug is. Can anybody help?

```
public class SumOddRange {
  public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (number % 2 > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

   public static int sumOdd (int start, int end) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

            if (isOdd(i) && end >= start && start > 0) {
                sum += i;
                return sum;
            }
        }
        return -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: `sumOdd` will always return after finding the first odd number

Comment: Do you have any example of what the program outputs for a given range, say start=1 and end=4

Comment: you should start with the lowest odd number and increase your for loop 2 by 2 since odd numbers will increase 2 by 2. your code is not working because your return sum is inside the if statement. you should return your sum outside of it when for loop is complete no matter if last i(in this case end) is odd or even.

Comment: maybe have a look at the warning intellij gives you? It clearly is the warning: "This for-loop doesn't loop"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you return the sum on first odd number you meet. Modify it like this, to return the sum only at the end to consider whole range:

```
public class SumOddRange {
  public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (number % 2 > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

   public static int sumOdd (int start, int end) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

            if (isOdd(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's my correct solution.

```
public class SumOddRange {

    public static boolean isOdd(int number) {

        if (number <= 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (number % 2 > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int sumOdd (int start, int end) {

        int sum = 0;

        if ((start < 0 || end < 0) || end < start) {
            return -1;
        } else if ((end >= start) && (start > 0 && end > 0)) {

            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (isOdd(i) ) {

                    sum += i;

                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see my solution. It works on the Udemy platform

```
public class SumOddRange {
public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (number % 2 > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {

    int sum = 0;
    if ((start > end) || (start < 0)) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

        if (isOdd(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are returning sum after the first odd number is found, thereby you calculate it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `return` in the `if-statement`. `return` exists the function and thus always returning on the first odd number.

Secondly you only need to check `isOdd` because this already checks if the number if greater than zero. And the for loop ensures `start < end`

This should do the trick:

```
public class SumOddRange {
  public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (number % 2 > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

   public static int sumOdd (int start, int end) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

            if (isOdd(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

Comment: I seem to have a problem here. sumOdd(10,5) gives 0 instead of -1. (Condition not met as start > end)

Comment: If you need to return -1 when start > end, just check before the for-loop: if(start > end) return -1; If you need to return -1 when the sum is 0 aswell, just put 1 check at the end: if (sum == 0) return -1; else return sum;

Answer (score 0):

@NiVeR has already provided the working solution. But to maybe include the comments from the question and other answers, here's the snippet which is improved:

```
public class SumOddRange {    
   public static int sumOdd (int start, int end) {
        // validation
        if(start > end){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException(start + " > " + end);
        }

        // empty sum is always 0
        int sum = 0;

        // if start is even, just increase by 1 to make it odd
        if(start % 2 == 0){
             start++;
        }

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i+=2) {
            // i will always be odd
            sum+=i;
        }

        return sum;
   }
}
```

You can see that you don't always have to check if a number is odd. Just do it once at the beginning then increment by `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also take a look at my solution below. I am exactly following what the challenge is asked to do. Here is the question: [image: Udemy Coding Exercise]

```
public class SumOddRange {

public static boolean isOdd(int number){
    if((number > 0) && (number % 2 != 0)){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static int sumOdd(int start, int end){
    int sum = 0;
    if(end >= start){
        if((start > 0) && (end > 0)){
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (isOdd(i)) {
                    sum = sum + i;
                }
            }
            //need to return sum after all odd numbers are found within range
            return sum;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

}